# Вывод результата рекурсии sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть табличка с такими данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой код для рекурсии

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT distinct
        M1.id id_t,
        M1.id,
        m1.id_dd
    FROM tmp_20102022v M1
   LEFT JOIN tmp_20102022v M2
          ON M1.id = M2.id_st
   WHERE M2.id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        C.id,
        M.id_st,
        m.id_dd
    FROM CTE C
        JOIN tmp_20102022v M
            ON C.id = M.id
)
SELECT c.id_t,c.id_dd FROM CTe c

group by c.id_t,c.id_dd
```

И получаю такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но никак не могу понять как сделать, чтобы в результате где id=1 были id_dd которые относятся к id=1 и id=2(как потомка), а в id=2 только id_dd которые id=2.
Как на примере ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не свои попытки её решить. ЗАЧЕМ нужен этот запрос, какую задачу он решает? [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169) + [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @Akina Есть id=1 в него входит определенные количество id_dd , в него входит еще подгруппа id _st = 2, а подгруппа id_st = 2 равняется полю id и здесь появляется рекурсия, потому что такое дерево может быть намного длиннее чем id 1 и 2 и простой джойн не поможет. 
И в результате нужно получить для каждого id всех тех кто есть в id_dd с учётом тех кто входит в потомки id_st. На скриншотах как раз хотел показать, что есть и что пытаюсь получить.